# Can't delete element in ndarray

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to delete the last element in an array, if the element does not meet certain conditions. The code I am using is:

```py
# Set the distibution parameter to 2
a = 2

# Set the size to 100
s = 100

# Create Zipf's Law distribution using a and s
x = np.random.zipf(a,s)

# Reorder list by number frequency
xb = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)

print("X",x)
print("XB",xb)

for i in reversed(xb):
    if xb[-1] > xb[-2]*1.5:
        xb = np.delete(xb,-1)

print("XB mod",xb)
print()
```

I get the following output for the `python print("X",x)` and ````python print("XB", xb):

> XB (array([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  28,
>   29,
>           31,  33,  56, 225]), array([57, 17,  4,  4,  2,  1,  2,  2,  2,  1,  2,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
>         dtype=int64))

However, when I try to run the deletion portion of the code, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test2.py", line 22, in
>   
>       if xb[-1] > xb[-2]*1.5: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Any idea how to fix it, so that I can delete the last element in the XB array, if it doesn't meet the condition?

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Comment: It makes sense. Raises other issues, but those I can fix. Thanks. Will accept in a few minutes

Comment: great. consider accepting my answer. cheers

Comment: In general, don't modify an object (`xb`) whilst you are iterating over it.

Comment: What is your expected result? And what do you want `if xb[-1] > xb[-2]*1.5` to do? `225 > 56 * 1.5`?

Comment: @Alexander; that is correct. If the element x+1 is 50% greater than x, then delete the element x+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xb` is a tuple consisting of a pair of `np.ndarray` objects.

> How do I delete the last element in the XB array, if it doesn't meet the condition

If you want to delete the last pair of zipped values (e.g. `225` and `1` for your data) based on your condition where you compare the last two numbers of the first row of data (e.g. `225 > 56 * 1.5` for your data):

```
if xb[0][-1] > xb[0][-2] * 1.5:
    xb = tuple(x[:-1] for x in xb)

>>> xb
(array([ 1,  2, ..., 31, 33, 56]), 
 array([57, 17, ...,  1,  1,  1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Use `all`:

```
for i in reversed(xb):
    if all(xb[-1] > xb[-2]*1.5): # use all here
        xb = np.delete(xb,-1)
```

Equivalent:  `if (xb[-1] > xb[-2]*1.5).all():`

---

**Long answer:**

You have:

```
xb
(array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  7,  9, 10, 13, 21, 22, 24, 30]),
 array([62, 16,  2,  4,  6,  3,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]))
```

that is a list of numpy arrays.

Next, `xb[-1] > xb[-2]*1.5` returns:

```
array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False])
```

If you do not use `all` OR `any`, this condition will raise the errror

Answer (score -2):

the problem is in `if xb[-1] > xb[-2]*1.5`

xb is not a scalar but a vector (1d array).

So what does it means v1 > v2? all items? at least one item?

Take for example [2,3] > [1,4], **all** will return False because 3 > 4, is False, **any** on the other hand, will return True because there is at least one that is true (2 > 1).

Like the error say it is **ambiguous**.

So, if for example you want that all the items will pass the condition you have to use:

```
if np.all(xb[-1] > xb[-2]*1.5): ...
```

Comment: Could you expand on the answer, as I am having trouble following the logic. The answer looks correct, but not the reason.

Comment: added example. hope it helps.I have no clue why i was down-voted.